# ubuntu 18.04 issues with gopro

Tags: shotwell

Under 16.04 I could download my gopro via shotwell after upgrading libgphoto. When I moved on to 18.04 everything worked fine for a while but not anymore. I have upgraded libgphoto once again but it doesn't seem to work anymore.Are there any other option than shotwell , if not what is the fix for this. Many thanks Jaq